# Убрать лишние символы в словах

Tags: python

```
line = ['ethdubai (3).db', 'https://t.me/aiogram_ru', 'ethdubai.db', 'telegram', '@markdown',
        '@metamaskofficialchat / Metamask | Offical Chat | ноя,2020']
for i in line:
    word = i.replace(f'.{i.split(".")[1]}', '')
    print(word)
```

У меня есть код где он убирает "." и выдает имена
но мне надо сделать более гибкий код

Те ссылки или названия групп надо взять основу

```
ethdubai
aiogram_ru
ethdubai
telegram
markdown
metamaskofficialchat
```

Как реализовать такой алгоритм

Comment: более гибкий в каком смысле? И вообще - что нужно удалять, что нужно оставлять?

Answer (score 1):

Предложу такой вариант. Поскольку принцип выбора слов из исходных текстов точно не определен, ориентировался на результат. Алгоритм следующий - с помощью регулярного выражения заменяем все символы, кроме буквенного или цифрового символа или знака подчёркивания, на пробел. Затем разрезаем по пробелам и находим самое длинное слово путем сортировки. Найденное слово выводим как результат.

```
import re

line = ['ethdubai (3).db', 'https://t.me/aiogram_ru', 'ethdubai.db', 'telegram', '@markdown',
        '@metamaskofficialchat / Metamask | Offical Chat | ноя,2020']
for i in line:
    word = sorted(re.sub(r'\W', ' ', i).split(), key=len, reverse=True)[0]
    print(word)
```

```
ethdubai
aiogram_ru
ethdubai
telegram
markdown
metamaskofficialchat
```

Comment: Можно через max переписать вместо sort: `word = max(re.sub(r'\W', ' ', i).split(), key=len)`. И можно в одну операцию разбивать на слова через `re.split(r'\W+', i)` вместо замены и потом вызова str.split

Comment: @insolor хорошее предложение!

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так

```
#К переменной можно более точное условие указать на что будет меняться
text_replace = ''
i.replace('то что хотим убрать', text_replace)
```

Comment: Результат replace нужно куда-то сохранять, replace не модифицирует исходную строку, а создает новую. К тому же мне "что-то" подсказывает, что автор вопроса знает о существовании этого метода.

Comment: Я знаю что результат replace нужно сохранять в переменную. Просто показал "часть" кода как можно было бы его модифицировать

Comment: Вы может и знаете, но приведенный пример может ввести кого-то в заблуждение.